# Quotient Banach space whose dual map sends the ball onto a given convex subset

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, convex-geometry

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $A$ be a closed, convex and balanced subset of $B_{X^{*}}$ (where $B_{X^{*}}$ denotes the closed unit ball of the dual $X^{*}$). Is there a closed subspace $M$ of $X$ such that $Q^{*}_{M}$ maps $B_{(X/M)^{*}}$ onto $A$, where $Q_{M}:X\rightarrow X/M$ is the quotient map?

Comment: What happens when $X=\mathbb{R}^n$?  Suppose $A$ is any closed convex balanced set with nonempty interior, other than the ball itself.  If $M \ne 0$ then $Q_M^*$ has rank less than $n$ and so its image cannot cover $A$, and if $M=0$ then $Q_M^*$ is the identity map and it maps the ball to itself.

Comment: Thanks, Nate. What happens if $X$ is infinite-dimensional?

Comment: I was just thinking about that.  More generally, the image of $Q_M^*$ will always equal the annihilator of $M$, right?  If $M \ne 0$ this is a proper closed subspace.  So take any $A$ which is not contained in a proper closed subspace (e.g. any $A$ with nonempty interior) and is not the ball, and I think that is a counterexample.

Comment: Indeed, $Q^{*}_{M}B_{(X/M)^{*}}$ is equal to the closed unit ball of the annilator of $M$. If we take $A$ with nonempty interior, then $M=0$.